# Delphi disconnecting TIdTCPClient in worker thread

Tags: delphi, indy

I need to send a TCP array of bytes via FMX application to a device. I have this interface:

```
type
  IPacketSend = interface
    procedure SendAsync(const Msg: String; OnSuccess: TSendSuccess; OnError: TSendError);
  end;
```

I have to use threading to not block the UI. This class actually sends the message, in a very simplified version:

```
type
  TPacketSenderLAN = class(TInterfacedObject, IPacketSend)
    private      
      FSelf: IPacketSend;
    public      
      procedure SendAsync(const Msg: String; OnSuccess: TSendSuccess; OnError: TSendError);
  end;

implementation

{ TPacketSender<T> }

procedure TPacketSenderLAN.SendAsync(const Msg: String; OnSuccess: TSendSuccess;
  OnError: TSendError);
begin
  TTask.Run(
    procedure
    var
      Client: TIdTCPClient;
      Exc: TObject;
    begin
      Client := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
      try
        try
          Client.Host := '192.168.0.213';
          Client.Port := 5200;
          Client.ConnectTimeout := 3500;

          Client.Connect;

          Data := TIdBytes(...);
          Client.Socket.Write(Data);

          TThread.Synchronize(nil,
            procedure
            begin
              OnSuccess;
              FSelf := nil;
            end
          );
        except
          on E: Exception do
            begin
              Exc := AcquireExceptionObject;

              TThread.Synchronize(nil,
                procedure
                begin
                  OnError(Exception(exc).Message);
                  FSelf := nil;
                end
              );
            end;
        end;
      finally
        Client.Free;
      end;
    end
  );
end;

end.
```

The `FSelf` variabile is absolutely needed because with `FSelf := Self;` in the constructor I prevent the reference count to go to 0 when the worker thread executes. In fact I call...

```
TThread.Synchronize(nil,
  procedure
    begin
      OnSuccess;
      FSelf := nil;
     end
);
```

... where `FSelf := nil;` is at the end so that the object is disposed when the job is done. I call it in this way from the code:

```
var
  PacketSender: IPacketSend;
begin
  PacketSender := TPacketSenderLAN.Create(...);
end;
```

---

Given the above scenario, my question is:

> am I using the TIdTCPClient safely? Do I have to disconnect it?

I don't know if I should call `Client.Disconnect;` inside the finally block. I think it's not needed because Free will destroy the `TIdTCPClient` and thus the client will disconnect. Is my code safe?

Comment: `TThread` increments its own refcount internally, so you don't need to keep a thread alive manually. `TTask` uses an anonymous thread that frees itself after your procedure exits. I see nothing in this code that requires `FSelf`. Also, I see no reason to use `AcquireExceptionObject()` since your use of `TThread.Synchronize()` could capture `E` directly, but better to save `E.Message` to a local variable and let `TThread.Synchronize()` capture that instead. Also, you are not calling `Client.Disconnect()` before calling `OnSuccess`/`OnError`. I would suggest using `TThread.Queue()`, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> am I using the TIdTCPClient safely?

Yes, you are.

`Data`, on the other hand, not so much, since it is not shown as being a local variable, or even a member of the `TPacketSenderLAN` class, which means it must be a global variable instead, and thus would be subject to multithread concurrency issues.  In this case, it should be a local variable.

> Do I have to disconnect it?

I would recommend it, yes, particularly before calling your `OnSuccess`/`OnError` handlers.  If you don't call `Disconnect()` manually, the TCP connection will not be disconnected until the `TIdTCPClient` destructor is called.  In this code, there is no reason for the TCP connection to remain active while your event handlers are running.

> I don't know if I should call `Client.Disconnect;` inside the `finally` block.

I would actually suggest adding *another* `try..finally` block just to call `Disconnect()`, eg:

```pascal
procedure
var
  Client: TIdTCPClient;
  Data: TIdBytes;
begin
  try
    Client := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
    try
      Client.Host := '192.168.0.213';
      Client.Port := 5200;
      Client.ConnectTimeout := 3500;

      Client.Connect;
      try      
        Data := TIdBytes(...);
        Client.IOHandler.Write(Data);
      finally
        Client.Disconnect;
      end;
    finally
      Client.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          OnError(E.Message);
        end
      );
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      OnSuccess;
    end
  );
end
```